# How to access AngualrJS $http.get method 'data' members

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, angularjs-scope, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to get a date value from one of my WEB API fields in AngualrJS controller in order to convert the date format.
here is what I have tried so far but apparently we cannot read the value from **data** parameter in $http.get method like the way I'm trying.

```
userApp.controller('userController', ['$scope', '$http',
function ($scope, $http) {
 $http.get('api/User').success(function(data) {
        $scope.users = data; //this line is working fine

        //this line is undefined
        $scope.date = data.BirthDate;  // this is always undefined!!
```

any help would be appreciated.

MY console.log(data) result as follow:

```
 [Object, Object]
 0: Object
       $$hashKey: "object:3"
       Address: "120 Nullasrbor Ave"
       BirthDate: "2014-10-22T00:00:00"
       CurrentSalary: 75000
       ....
 1: Object
       ....
```

The good solution to get this done was provided by @denisazevedo
mainly to use the date itself inside the view rather than the js controller:

{{user.BirthDate| date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}

Comment: BithDate or BirthDate ? :) post ur api part as well

Comment: it's BirthDate but the actual issue is how to access the **data** members ?

Comment: what do u get on console.log(data);

Comment: data can fill by api with no issue, my question is how to access to the members of the data?

Comment: Why Down Vote??, I have looked up everywhere before I post this question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to debug and inspect the `data` object to see what's returning.

Edited: try this one:

```
$scope.date = data.data.BirthDate || data.BirthDate;
```

Again, check what exactly your `data` object is at the debug or put it in your code:

```
console.log(data);
```

Based on the return object, it is an array.
You can get it iterating over this array or specifying the position:

```
data[0].BirthDate
```

--

To display the dates in a table, do this (with given date format):

```
<span ng-repeat="user in users">{{user.BirthDate | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</span>
```

Comment: thanks for reply but the problem is **$scope.date** NOT $scope.users

Comment: I have more than 1 members, how would I apply that to all of them inside the controller ?

Comment: Do you want to display these dates on a view?

Comment: @AliShahrokhi You'll need to iterate over your collection and display the dates. Check my last edit.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that, and I have iterate over the object the problem is it will always show th value of the first record in every row

Comment: Did you use the line of code I wrote? Open a chat so we can discuss this better and avoid discussions in comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63537/discussion-between-ali-shahrokhi-and-denisazevedo).

Answer (score 2):

try this one,

```
data[0].BirthDate

$http.get('api/User').success(function(data) {
    $scope.date = [];
    for (key in data) {
         $scope.date.push(data[key].BirthDate);
     }
....
```

Comment: Thanks for that so how could I do that for all of the members as this is more than one date ?

Comment: do u have `birthday` in every Object ? do u need to get the `birthday` in all of the Objects ?

Comment: Yes I do there is a list of objects that I need to display them in a table

Comment: the answer above gives me an error **undefined is not a function**

Comment: passed the error after your update, but this will repeat the BirthDate in each line(for example two dates in each row)!?